# Cannot Import WTF

Tags: python, flask, pip, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a virtualbox running centOS. I want to install WTForms and Flask_WTF. I have installed them using pip. However, there are import errors.

```
[vagrant@oclubs ~]$ pyshell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/oclubs/repo/shell.py", line 12, in <module>
    from oclubs import *
  File "/srv/oclubs/repo/oclubs/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from oclubs import objs
  File "/srv/oclubs/repo/oclubs/objs/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from oclubs.objs.classroom import Classroom
  File "/srv/oclubs/repo/oclubs/objs/classroom.py", line 7, in <module>
    from wtforms import BooleanField, SelectMultipleField
ImportError: No module named wtforms
```

Flask imports are fully functional. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are sometimes many python interpreters (which *searches* packages in different folders) and pips (which *install* packages to a different folders) installed. You can check where your interpreter searches packages by adding a code just before line which caused an error: `import sys, os; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable); print(os.environ['PATH']); print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')); print(os.getcwd())`. Then run `pip show wtforms` and see where it was installed. If it's not in the PATH or PYTHONPATH, then pay attention to the pip, which you've used to install a package.

P.S. If you are using virtual env, ensure that you are installing a package with this env's pip, not your system's pip.

Answer (score 0):

Please install again with user vagrant and try again. I assume you've installed in root user or anything.

`[vagrant@oclubs ~]$ pip install WTForms`